# How to add a column in a csv file (at middle and end) in bash linux using awk?

Tags: csv, awk

The input.csv is:

```
id, name, shortName
1, Example1, Ex1
2, Example2, Ex2
```

I need to add a column of date. So the output.csv should be:

```
id, 2021-06-23, name, shortName
1,  2021-06-23, Example1, Ex1
2,  2021-06-23, Example2, Ex2.
```

For this purpose, i used this comand:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { FS=OFS = "," } {$2="2021-06-23"; print}' input.csv
```

But, when i did it the column "name" was deleted. The output was like this:

```
id, 2021-06-23, shortName
1,  2021-06-23, Ex1
2,  2021-06-23, Ex2.
```

Then, i also tried put the colum at the end with the comand:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { FS=OFS = "," } {$4="2021-06-23"; print}' input.csv
```

But the exit was even stranger:

```
,  2021-06-23 
,  2021-06-23
,  2021-06-23
```

So, I would like to know what I'm doing wrong both in the case of adding a column to the middle of the csv file and adding it to the end.

Obs.: I am now learning how to use it and therefore I believe that my mistakes must be a beginner's mistakes.

Comment: Your source file probably has Windows line endings (`\r\n`) and therefore the latter output is a mess. `RS="\r\n"` probably fixes that. To get the expected output, `$2="2021-06-23" OFS $2` should work.

Comment: @JamesBrown, don´t work

Comment: Please don't tell me just _don't work_, be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { FS=OFS = "," } {$2="2021-06-23"; print}' input.csv
```

does overwrite 2nd column using `2021-06-23`. Note also that this code is redundant - you are setting field seperator twice, once using `-F` then setting `FS` in `BEGIN`, code above has same effect as

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS = "," } {$2="2021-06-23"; print}' input.csv
```

You want to add column, if you know in advance number of columns in your .csv file you might do, for 3 columns:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{print $1,"2021-06-23",$2,$3}' input.csv
```

which for `input.csv` content being

```
id, name, shortName
1, Example1, Ex1
2, Example2, Ex2
```

output

```
id, 2021-06-23, name, shortName
1, 2021-06-23, Example1, Ex1
2, 2021-06-23, Example2, Ex2
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: If I have a large number of columns, is there any way to just specify where to insert? Because "{print $1,"2021-06-23",$2,$3}" in this part of the code I have to put the numbering of the other columns.

Comment: @Lucas if you want to add new column value after certain column, let say 1st then do `{$1=$1 OFS "2021-06-23";print}` it does replace content of 1st column with content of 1st column followed by output field separator followed by `2021-06-23`